# fabric2 using a private key

Tags: python, fabric

So i have this little script :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from fabric2 import Connection

c = Connection('192.168.1.666',connect_kwargs={"key_filename": "privatekey"})


c.local('touch test3.txt')


#with c.cd('/home/gaiman/productmicro'):
    #c.run('git pull origin master')

with c.cd('/home/gaiman/productmicro'):
    c.run('touch test4.txt')
```

The problem is that i have a problem with the privatekey :

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/paramiko/pkey.py", line 289, in _read_private_key
    raise SSHException("not a valid " + tag + " private key file")
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: not a valid RSA private key file
```

The private key is in the same folder of the script however.

I don't understand

Comment: Did you set up a passphrase for your private key?

Comment: @OluwafemiSule nope but i found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

So i needed to create specific keys for fabric :

Generate keys for fabric  :

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096
```

This will generate a SSH key by using the RSA algorithm.

and take care to properly name them id_rsa any other name might cause havoc in fabric

Comment: Does the location matter? It still doesn't work for me :(

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your issue is because Fabric does not support the use of key file formats such as PKCS#8 at the moment. Fabric uses Paramiko to create ssh connections which can only use PKCS#1 files. This is known unfixed issue in Paramiko. See https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/1015

PKCS#1 RSA files typically look like this. If there's no 'RSA', then it's probably a PKCS#8, which is generated by default on more modern openssl versions.

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
baSe64...
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

The conversion is simple:

```
openssl rsa -in private_pkcs8.pem -out private_pkcs1.pem
```